# Simple high-level overview of how to handle Vuejs authentication with JWT

Tags: vuejs2, jwt, router

Just need a high level overview of how to architect this. 
I have an Authentication js object (es6 class) that is instantiated once, and uses JWT.

```
import { getRouteByName, getRouter } from 'appRouter'
import axios from 'axios'

let instance = null
class AppAuthentication {
  constructor (http, router, localStorage = window.localStorage) {
    if (!instance) {
      instance = this
      this.storage = localStorage
      this.http = http
      // this.router = router // but it will be undefined
      this.api = http.create({baseURL: someURL, headers: {'Authorization':
      'Bearer ' + this.token}})
      this.watchRoutes()
    }
    return instance
  }

  watchRoutes () {
    this.router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      let login = 'Login'
      if (to.name !== login && this.isLoggedOut()) {
      return next(getRouteByName(login))
    }
    next()
  })
  }
  login (credentials) {
    return this.http.post(`${SOME_URL}/login`, credentials)
  }

  finishAuthentication (token) {
    this.setToken(token)
    this.router.replace('/')
  }
  logout () {...}
  set token (token) { ... }
  get token () { ... }
  get router: () => getRouter() // this sucks
  isLoggedIn () {...}
  isLoggedOut () {...}
}
export default new AppAuthentication(axios, router /*(here router will be undefined)*/ )
```

The problem is that that is object is instantiated before Vue Router is "ready" so the reference is undefined. I have a crappy getter that reaches back to vue router. Clearly this is not the best way.

I have seen high level components in reactJS land that would wrap the contents on the app. Haven't seen anything like this is vue. What's generally the high level way to do this?

Something like this the way to do it?

```
<app>
  <authentication>
    <some-tag></some-tag>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </authentication>
</app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the authentication object you have. I would recommend using Vuex to maintain your user state rather than storing it in local storage. Your 'get token' can be an action and your 'set token' a mutation. You can mirror Vuex to localStorage using [Persisted State](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate).

Here's how I've handled the JWT token:

1) Require token for all routing calls except Login. You do this in the before router guard. So something like this in routes.js if using localStorage:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
let now = new Date()
if (/login|reset|activate|forgot/.test(to.path.toLowerCase())) {
    next()
}
else if (localStorage.getItem('token') && localStorage.getItem('tokenExpires') > now){
    next()
}
else {
    next('/login')
}
```

2) Handle 403 or other auth errors so they route to login or wherever you want it to go. On my current app we use GraphQL with Fetch and all requests go through one GraphQL.js file, so we have one simple place for logic dealing with handling requests.

3) Handle logging in api calls on Login component itself, sending the response to Vuex mutations or storing it in local/session storage.

A great benefit of Vue is its simplicity. A tip: when you can, put relevant functions you are not reusing elsewhere right on the components themselves. It is more intuitive and makes the code more maintainable going forward.

Comment: In the end I made an auth object that takes the router and store as an dependencies. It handles interfacing with localstorage, and only emits to vuex a boolean if the user is logged in or not. It's not far away from what you're saying. It's a broad question... so you've earned yourself a tick.

Comment: @Simon, thanks. I will say that in my experience you want to save the token into State and not local storage. I did a side by side comparison and it was much slower to use local storage and I had to treat it like pulling from an API. For example, an app I worked on required high security and changed the token on every request. Storing and pulling it from local storage didn't work because the delay in writing and in reading was enough that it would sometimes not get the correct token or other times it would come back blank. Overall, my experience is that Vue is 'too fast' for local storage